What is the recommended way to share code in MS Teams?
This is my usual workflow:

Type anything I want to say in my favourite editor (Emacs in my case)
This includes text AND code snippets
Once I am ready, I copy paste to the communication tool I need to use (StackOverflow or whatever)

In the case of MS Teams, this does not work: code snippets are simply not properly formatted.
In order to have my messages properly formatted, I have to go through an ordeal of selecting, hightlighting, changing format of certain sections, for my messages not to appear as unprofessional gibberish.
There must be a better way. Any ideas?
(tagging as msteams for lack of a better tag)

Code snippets work. You can select from some 30 language options for proper syntaxes highlighting. But you need to include the snippet as a snippet, not just copy-pasting all your text in the message chat. So copy text, then snippet, text, etc. It takes more time, but otherwise everything is dumped as text

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-code-snippets-in-a-message-in-microsoft-teams-5406fe2b-2771-4b9a-bd73-656914f6ab3c

@Bogdan; which means I can not copy paste from my editor, but have to deal with the clunky MS Teams editor and do a ton of highlighting and clicking around just to get something that any old markdown visualizer gives me out of the box. I was used to Slack, which is much superior in this regard.

Slack originated from a developer communication tool. MSTeams was built to compete with it, but I guess more effort was spent integrating MSTeams with the rest of the Microsoft ecosystem than to having the same feature set. I also prefer Slack, but if you need to use MSTeams, that's the only way I know how to format code. Maybe others have better suggestions.
